# Qt GUI -> Code based to Designer based

Tags: c++, qt, refactoring, qt-designer

I am currently working on some old code [legacy to some extent]. 
Recently, we got a requirement to change the size of the display.
At this point, I realized that the ui is generated from code. This makes changes to the code pretty irritating to say the least [We are not looking to just expand the ui components, but also to move some functionality from the menu bar to the screen].

Hence for the requirement and possible future changes, I would prefer to morph the code to a designer based ui making future code changes easier [also I really really don't want to dwell into the complex code that exists, nor do I want the next guy to curse me as I am cursing my predecessor].

I was wondering if someone came across a similar problem and devised some steps for doing the same. I checked up on the net, I didn't find a any proper guides/recommendations, so i came here bearing imaginary cookies.

Comment: Does the existing code follow the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) pattern?

Comment: Sorry, for not replying earlier, I was on vacation and really didn't want to think about work. @thuga yes, it follows MVC.

Comment: So you can create a new UI without worrying about breaking the existing code. Or you can modify the existing code by attaching a designer form to it, and replace all variables like `closeButton` with `ui->closeButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, honestly only way is to "redraw" them, but, what I would suggest as something in the middle is (this is what I use for many years) - as I am not a fun of UI compiler,

1) you draw your interface in the .ui files
2) load QWidget * using uitools (from the documentation)

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent)
 {
  QUiLoader loader;
  QFile file(":/forms/myform.ui");
  file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
  QWidget *myWidget = loader.load(&file, this);

  QPushButton * pBtn = myWidget->findChild<QPushButton*>("myButton");

  file.close();

  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(myWidget);
  setLayout(layout);
}
```

that way you can pretty safely move all UI into designer, while keeping your code with already declared controls more or less intact, only you will need some sort of resolveControls() function which will find and attach controls needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to avoid doing that as i feared it might be confusing if someone other than me starts to read it. Guess i'll be writing large blocks of comments.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, it's much easier to read as long as you keep consistency between names in UI and C++ variable names, so if for example you look for - from where m_btnOk goes, you can assume that it's same name UI element